Website content doesn't change when I manually enter URL and append locale in Next Js and React i18n
I am using these packages and this function to change the language of our Next Js 14 website:
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import i18nConfig from '@/i18nConfig';

const handleLanguageChange = (lang) => {
      
    // const newLocale = e.target.value;
    const newLocale = lang;

    setIsLoading(true)

    // return;

    // set cookie for next-i18n-router
    const days = 30;
    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = `NEXT_LOCALE=${newLocale};expires=${expires};path=/`;

    // redirect to the new locale path
    if (
      currentLocale === i18nConfig.defaultLocale &&
      !i18nConfig.prefixDefault
    ) {
      
      router.push('/' + newLocale + currentPathname);

    } else {

      router.push(
        currentPathname.replace(`/${currentLocale}`, `/${newLocale}`)
      );


    }

    router. Refresh();

    }

Everything works fine when I use the language switcher select dropdown which fires the handleLanguageChange() functions to change the language to the preferred one. However, if a user should enter the website URL with the locale appended like this www.domain.com/fr, the language doesn't change until I use the language switcher dropdown. How do I achieve this?
